# How to interprete ffmpeg AVERROR

Tags: c, error-handling, ffmpeg

Anybody knows where is a list of the AVERROR meanings? Something like

```
-1: reason A
-2: reason B
```

and so forth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go (taken from [libavutil/error.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/error_8c.html)):

```
{ ERROR_TAG(BSF_NOT_FOUND),      "Bitstream filter not found"                     },
{ ERROR_TAG(BUG),                "Internal bug, should not have happened"         },
{ ERROR_TAG(BUG2),               "Internal bug, should not have happened"         },
{ ERROR_TAG(BUFFER_TOO_SMALL),   "Buffer too small"                               },
{ ERROR_TAG(DECODER_NOT_FOUND),  "Decoder not found"                              },
{ ERROR_TAG(DEMUXER_NOT_FOUND),  "Demuxer not found"                              },
{ ERROR_TAG(ENCODER_NOT_FOUND),  "Encoder not found"                              },
{ ERROR_TAG(EOF),                "End of file"                                    },
{ ERROR_TAG(EXIT),               "Immediate exit requested"                       },
{ ERROR_TAG(EXTERNAL),           "Generic error in an external library"           },
{ ERROR_TAG(FILTER_NOT_FOUND),   "Filter not found"                               },
{ ERROR_TAG(INVALIDDATA),        "Invalid data found when processing input"       },
{ ERROR_TAG(MUXER_NOT_FOUND),    "Muxer not found"                                },
{ ERROR_TAG(OPTION_NOT_FOUND),   "Option not found"                               },
{ ERROR_TAG(PATCHWELCOME),       "Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome" },
{ ERROR_TAG(PROTOCOL_NOT_FOUND), "Protocol not found"                             },
{ ERROR_TAG(STREAM_NOT_FOUND),   "Stream not found"                               },
{ ERROR_TAG(UNKNOWN),            "Unknown error occurred"                         },
```

But this is version-dependent way and it is better to use `av_strerror()` to let the library give you a string representation of the error code.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`av_strerror()`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__error.html#g5792b4a2d18d7d9cb0efbcfc335dce24) to get a string representation of the error code.

If you simply want to look it up, you can refer to the docs for [libavutil/error.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/error_8c.html) and [libavutil/error.h](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/error_8h.html).

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
printf("%s", av_err2str(ret));
```

where ret is the integer returned from a function (e.g. avformat_open_input(...)).

Answer (score -1):

Note that most functions return a NEGATIVE error.  So you have to call  av_strerror(-returnvalue)